# java notes api search emails for last 5 days

Tags: lotus-notes

Hi I have written a java program using notes apis using classes
lotus.domino.Database and lotus.domino.DocumentCollection;
In this program I need to search emails for last x days or x hours and then read them.

I am using Date > [11/11/2018] in  dc = db.search(searchString); but its not returning any mail from last five  days. its not returning any mail at all.

I also tried SELECT (@Created) >= @Adjust(@TextToTime("Today");0;0;-5;0;0;0) its returning some mails but not all the mails from last 5 days.
PLease note i am using java program and i need to find email from a replica .nsf file for the mails in last x days. Please suggest a reliable method. thanks

Comment: @TextToTime("Today") -> @Today => SELECT (@Created) >= @Adjust(@Today;0;0;-5;0;0;0)

Comment: The item name is either DeliveredDate (received messages) or PostedDate (sent messages), not "Date".

Comment: Thanks Richard DeliveredDate > [11/11/2018] solution worked for me.